# Compile error: 'RtlCaptureStackBackTrace' undefined

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, backtrace

I'm trying to add a simple backtrace function to a C project which is built with Visual Studio 2012, and for some reason it gives me this compile error on the call to `CaptureStackBackTrace()`:

```
10>c:\...\stacktrace.h(112): warning C4013: 'RtlCaptureStackBackTrace' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

The build is configured with cmake. According to the MSN docs, `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` is the backing implementation of `CaptureStackBackTrace`, but I don't see why there would be any problem finding it. My includes are:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
```

I'm not very familiar with C projects in general, and this is my first project on Windows in about 15 years, so I really don't know what might be wrong. The project is quite large, and everything else builds fine.

Comment: You need to set the _WIN32_WINNT macro value to at least 0x0600 to avoid this error.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx